# Git (Sourcetree) branching and merging - not sure what I did

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, sourcetree

So I started out with a master branch and I decided I wanted to make a new branch called "Splitting_Pen_Into_Two_Components". I branched, made some changes, committed, and pushed to the new branch. I'm noticing now that I never actually saw the branch (purple line). Is there a way for me to get back to the master with my current files?

My guess is that I created a new repository because I see two origins. Is that correct? Can anyone understand what I did?

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: You are one commit on top of origin/splittnig which is two commits on top of origin/master. Everything looks normal

Answer (score 1):

You've not created a new repository; you're on a separate branch and you happen to be a commit ahead of your remote branch.  Remote branches are prefixed with `origin/`, and the canonical master branch is `origin/master`.

You should seek to push your work to the remote at your earliest convenience.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get back to master branch with current files (i.e current changes which are commited based on the image you posted above), simply you have to ***merge your current branch into master***.

When you push your new branch to "server or remote repository" then it will be shown as "origin/(your branch name)". It's showing two origins because **two branches are present in the "server or remote repository"**.

At this instance, if you make a commit to master, by simply switching to master, without merging your branch in to master. Then you can **see the purple line to differentiate that, commits are made in different branches**.

Comment: http://imgur.com/4Uoa6cW I merged the current (new) branch with master but the current branch is still the new branch. The master icons aren't on top, though, so I don't think I have actually merged with master.